# From an excel file, is there a way in Python to get the MAC AP address that has the highest sum between two columns and in a range of dates?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying in Python to get the MAC AP address that has the highest traffic (highest Input octets + Output octets) in a range of dates. I tried with pandas but I keep getting stuck, so I'm not sure if is there a more efficient way to do it.

[Here's a pic of how the excel is designed, it has 45200 rows if that is useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnQoo.png)

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I would create another column with the sum of Input octets and Output octets, and search for the row with the highest value of it. Something like `df['Octets'] = df['Input octets'] + df['Output octets']`, and then `val = df['Octets'].max()`, and then `df[df['Octets'] == val]['MAC AP']`

Comment: That definitely helped me a lot. I was probably overthinking this too much and getting stuck at the dates range part. Thank you very much @LifeisGood

Comment: No worries. I think the standard thing to do when posting on the forum, is to provide some code of what you have done so far, so people can go off of it when diagnosing the problem. The picture was definitely helpful, though!